Not receiving notifications from firebase console - React native firebase iOS cloud messaging
I have been trying firebase push notifications on react native. I have used this docs (https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage/ios-setup) and the steps that mentioned.
Setup ios project on firebase console
Same bundle identifier as in my xcode under signing & capabilties
Downloaded GoogleService-Info.plist and configured
Added capabilities of Push notifications and background fetch
Setup APN key
Uploaded the created APN key on firebase cloud messaging
I can get the token. But, When I tried to hit the notification from the firebase console using the generated token means, I am not getting any notification on foreground, background or killed state
